# While Installing gstreamer-sdk-dev... i got this.... please help...?

Tags: ubuntu-sdk, gstreamer

While installing gstreamer-sdk-dev i got this...!!!

```
E: Failed to fetch http://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/packages/ubuntu/raring/amd64/./gstreamer-sdk-gstreamer-clutter-dev_2013.6-1_amd64.deb  Failed to connect to www.freedesktop.org port 443: Network is unreachable

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Answer (score 2):

freedesktop.org was down for a while last night. However you should never ever use the "gstreamer-sdk", or anything from gstreamer.com at this point.

It's a project created by two companies that is unrelated to the GStreamer project, and nowadays provides completely outdated versions (with an older API) of GStreamer and as a result is full of bugs.

Get the latest packages from your Ubuntu, they're going to be newer unless you use an Ubuntu release from 2013. And use GStreamer 1.x, not the outdated 0.10 version.

Answer (score 0):

This link 'http://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/packages/ubuntu/raring/amd64/gstreamer-sdk-gstreamer-clutter-dev_2013.6-1_amd64.deb' is working fine...please check your internet connection.